# Interleaving position

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, periodic-function

How could I proceed to interleave the presented values to obtain the same result obtained by this code?

```
x1 = 85; y1 = 570; x2 = 250; y2 = 150; Δx = 165;

pos = {
  {x1, y1},
  {x1, y2},
  {x2, y2},
  {x2, y1},
  {x2 + Δx, y1},
  {x2 + Δx, y2},
  {x2 + 2 Δx, y2},
  {x2 + 2 Δx, y1},
  {x2 + 3 Δx, y1},
  {x2 + 3 Δx, y2},
  {x2 + 4 Δx, y2},
  {x2 + 4 Δx, y1},
  {x2 + 5 Δx, y1},
  {x2 + 5 Δx, y2},
  {x2 + 6 Δx, y2},
  {x2 + 6 Δx, y1},
  {x2 + 7 Δx, y1},
  {x2 + 7 Δx, y2}}

Graphics[{Line[pos]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Look at `Piecewise`, or `SquareWave[{max, min}, x]`.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines?

```
x1 = 85; y1 = 570; x2 = 250; y2 = 150; Δx = 165;

Plot[
  SquareWave[{y2, y1}, (x - x2)/(2 Δx)], {x, 85 - 1, 1405 + 1},
  ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Thanks to [Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26598/roman) for the fix on the horizontal offset that had slipped by!)

---

An alternative exploiting `InterpolationOrder` within `ListPlot`:

```
plot = 
 ListLinePlot[
   {{x1, y1}} ~ Join ~ Partition[Riffle[Range[x1, x1 + 9 Δx, Δx], {y2, y1}], 2],
   InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
 ]
```

Incidentally, if you need the list itself, you can extract it from the plot above:

```
First@Cases[plot, l_Line :> Rationalize@l[[1]], All]
```

> `{{85, 570}, {85, 570}, {85, 150}, {250, 150}, {250, 570}, 
>     {415, 570}, {415, 150}, {580, 150}, {580, 570}, {745, 570}, 
>     {745, 150}, {910, 150}, {910, 570}, {1075, 570}, {1075, 150}, 
>     {1240, 150}, {1240, 570}, {1405, 570}, {1405, 150}}`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: to get the horizontal offset right: `Plot[SquareWave[{y2, y1}, (x - x2)/(2 Δx)], {x, 0, 1400}, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: @Roman Good point, thank you for adding that. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
pos2 = Drop[Join @@ NestList[{2 Δx, 0} + # & /@ # &, 
        Tuples[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]], 4], -2] ;

pos2 == pos
```

> True

```
ListLinePlot[pos2]
```

[image]